Multiple Lazy chunk files for one lazy loading module in angular
I have two lazy loading modules in my Angular application. Once I built the application, I noticed that 2 lazy chunk files are generated for same module with same name, as shown below.
Lazy chunk files              | Names                          |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
60.1880044024f2f918.js        | school-school-module           | 294.00 kB |                42.99 kB
636.cfdf85a3918d31b8.js       | student-student-module         | 234.85 kB |                32.28 kB
307.b581d1c3aea312a1.js       | student-student-module         | 89.09 kB  |                18.05 kB
common.f8f6f07a0903bb8e.js    | common                         |   1.57 kB |               646 bytes

This is not causing any issues when running the application and everything is working as expected. However, I need a clarification on why two files are generated for student-module.
I tried setting "optimization": true and "namedChunks": true in angular.json, but no luck.

do you have dynamic imports import(...) inside of stuldent module files?

No, I dont have any dynamic imports@Andrei

If the student-module is importing other shared modules or components, Angular's build process may split these into separate chunks to optimize load times. This could result in multiple chunks being named similarly if they are part of the same lazy-loaded module.
